# TIN interpolation from LiDAR point data excluding no-data areas (for water)

Tags: tin, breaklines

I am working with LiDAR data for a specific marsh area. The data is in x,y,z point files. When loading this layer, it is clear that in the creeks of the marsh, no data points were measured with the LiDAR (because of the presence of water in the creeks at time). When I perform a TIN interpolation however, the no data parts (creeks) are still interpolated, which is probably skewing the resulting DTM.
I've tried using breaklines in the TIN interpolation to exclude the creek areas with no data points, but then the resulting image still includes this creek area (with very diverging elevations inside the creek area).

This is what I've done in the TIN interpolation using breaklines

```
QGIS code revision: 654e76b3cb
Qt version: 5.11.2
GDAL version: 3.1.4
GEOS version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ version: Rel. 6.3.2, May 1st, 2020
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'TIN interpolation' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'EXTENT' : '148996.216800000,149565.618900000,210533.096900000,211123.716200000 [EPSG:31370]', 'INTERPOLATION_DATA' : 'C:/Users/LIDAR/LiDAR_new/BW_2014_clipped_xyz.gpkg|layername=BW_2014_clipped_xyz::~::1::~::-1::~::0::|::MultiLineString?crs=EPSG:31370&field=fid:long(0,0)&uid={c35efefe-93ff-4ee4-a305-18620c0578cf}::~::0::~::0::~::2', 'METHOD' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'PIXEL_SIZE' : 0.1 }

Execution completed in 23.85 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users//OUTPUT.tif',
'TRIANGULATION': ''}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'TIN interpolation' finished
```

Is there a way to do this interpolation without taking into account the no data points, so the resulting DTM is the marsh area, with just an empty/no data area of where the creek is?

(I'm using QGIS 3.16 and have no experience with Python)